# Pushing Django app to heroku throws error "ImportError: No module named djangocms_history"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku, virtualenv

I have a Django project that I am trying to push to heroku.  My requirements.txt file is

```
Django==1.11.18
django-cms==3.5.3
django-sekizai==0.10.0
django-treebeard==4.3
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.9
```

When I try to deploy to heroku I get the following error:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
remote:            __import__(name)
remote:        ImportError: No module named djangocms_history
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to udsa-content-repository.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/udsa-content-repository.git
 ! [remote rejected] fixing-heroku-build -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/udsa-content-repository.git'
```

I was getting that same error `ImportError: No module named djangocms_history` when trying to run commands on my local before I activated `virtualenv` so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `requirements.txt` file seems to be missing:

```
djangocms-history==1.0.0
```

Comment: But the project runs locally just fine when all I did was pip install based on my requirements.txt file, why would cause an error on heroku and not my local?

Comment: Your environment must already have `djangocms-history` installed. Check with `pip freeze`. Heroku creates a new clean environment, so you'd need to do that too for a better test locally.

Comment: Ah, yea, there a lot of missing packages when I did pip freeze. Thanks

Comment: Some of those might be dependencies of the packages you do have in `requirements.txt`. [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree) or similar may help there. Also consider using [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which helps you maintain a clean environment.

Answer (score 1):

- run `pip install djangocms-history`
- add `djangocms_history` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`
- run `python manage.py migrate djangocms_history`

Answer (score 1):

You have an [`ImportError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ImportError).

[`ImportError` for python2.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ImportError)

Go to your code, search your entire code base for `djangocms_history`

Then either `pip install djangocms_history`, restart your wsgi, and try it out.

Or comment it out, and anything that uses it. Then try running again.

Depending on what it is, you might also have to make migrations and migrate too.